# Fixed width div on left and Disqus on right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my 2 elements display one next to each other.

```
<footer>
  <div id="left">....</div>
  <div id="disqus_thread">....</div>
</footer>
```

Here are various things that I have tried and didn't work:

```css
footer {display: table;}
#left {display: table-cell; width: 500px;}
#disqus_thread {display: table-cell; width: auto;}
```

another that didn't work:

```css
footer {display: block;}
#left {display: inline-block; float: left; width: 500px;}
#disqus_thread {display: inline-block; float: right;}
```

and a few other combinations that involve `float/left/right` or `overflow:auto`.

one big problem is that my Disqus thread ends up being `1px` in width many times.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CSS table layout should work, but you'd better to set a `width` to the table, also worth to set a `vertical-align` value to the cells.

Because, table has the "shrink to fit" feature, and I guess the Disqus form is loaded from an `iframe` so width of the form depends on the container.

```css
footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 500px;
}
#disqus_thread {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you prefer to use `float`, you can use `calc()`, and don't forget to clear the floats.

```css
footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
}
#disqus_thread {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way.

```
<style>
footer {display: inline-block; width:100%;}
#left { float:left; width: 50%; background:#ccc; }
#disqus_thread { float:right; width:50%; background:#666;}
</style>

<footer>
  <div id="left">....</div>
  <div id="disqus_thread">....</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: My question was specific about having one element's width in % and the other in px

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most cases to display the elements inline.

```css
footer{
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}
div#left{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
div#disqus_thread{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="left">First</div>
  <div id="disqus_thread">Second</div>
</footer
```